# modify WXS file generated by heat through Xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, wix

I am editing component of all .config files in  directory.wxs by xslt.

1) I am unable to go to parent element(component) after reaching child element(file)

2) It is overriding all the attributes rather than appending to original attributes.

my xslt file

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
                    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" 
                    xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
                    xmlns:my="my:my">

          <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>

          <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

          <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
          </xsl:template>

          <xsl:template match='/wix:Wix/wix:Fragment/wix:DirectoryRef/wix:Directory/wix:Directory/wix:Component/wix:File[@Source="SourceDir\Debug\settings.xml"]'>
            <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select=".." mode="backout"/>
                    <xsl:attribute name="Permanent">
                        <xsl:text>yes</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:copy>
          </xsl:template>

        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

input.wxs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
        <Fragment>
            <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
                <Directory Id="dirEF46C7404B50F3071431995F0F04741E" Name="bin">
                        <Component Id="cmp1B2A20D6C7B8EEB0F3E75C2D993AAC13" Guid="1346D980-EE76-4E6D-BA63-F1F0BB5A860D">
                            <File Id="fil46D415998FC8ECAB7106CB3185135601" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\Debug\settings.xml" />
                        </Component>
                    </Directory>
                </Directory>
            </DirectoryRef>
        </Fragment>
```

output.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
        <Fragment>
            <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
                <Directory Id="dirEF46C7404B50F3071431995F0F04741E" Name="bin">
                        <Component Id="cmp1B2A20D6C7B8EEB0F3E75C2D993AAC13" Guid="1346D980-EE76-4E6D-BA63-F1F0BB5A860D">
                            <File Permanent="yes" />
                        </Component>
                    </Directory>
                </Directory>
            </DirectoryRef>
        </Fragment>
```

requiredoutput.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
        <Fragment>
            <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
                <Directory Id="dirEF46C7404B50F3071431995F0F04741E" Name="bin">
                        <Component Id="cmp1B2A20D6C7B8EEB0F3E75C2D993AAC13" Guid="1346D980-EE76-4E6D-BA63-F1F0BB5A860D" Permanent="yes" >
                            <File Id="fil46D415998FC8ECAB7106CB3185135601" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\Debug\settings.xml" />
                        </Component>
                    </Directory>
                </Directory>
            </DirectoryRef>
        </Fragment>
```

Comment: Please update your XMLs to be well formed. What is the purpose of traversing to the parent element?

Comment: The permanent = yes should be defined in the component tag and not the file tag

Comment: @abhinavpandey What is the meaning of your edit? OP wanted the add the `permanent` attribute to the `File` element, not to the `Component`. How come you know more about this than he/she does?

Comment: It is wix, the permanent attribute is part of the file tag :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="wix:File[@Source='SourceDir\Debug\settings.xml']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="Permanent">yes</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

> I am unable to go to parent element(component) after reaching child
>   element(file)

I see no need to do so. If you want to modify the parent, you can do it simply by adding a template matching `Component` and let it execute **before** reaching the child.

Note also that your stylesheet tries to apply template to the parent of `File` using `mode="backout"` -  but it contains no templates in such mode.

In any case, your expected output shows no change to the parent `Component`, so this is all theoretical.

---

### Edit:

*In response to your edited question and the clarification in the comment below:*

> I want to add attribute in the component for which corresponding child
>   (File elemeny) satisfy the condition that
>   **source="SourceDir\Debug\settings.xml"**

Change the second template to:

```
<xsl:template match="wix:Component[wix:File/@Source='SourceDir\Debug\settings.xml']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="Permanent">yes</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: But Dont have any previous information about my component because my   directory.wxs file is generated by WIX heat command.   All I can do to uniquely identify that component is by its child element that is File

Comment: @Keshav I am afraid I don't understand what you're trying to say. Do you want to modify the `File` or the `Component`? If it is the `Component`, can there be *other* `Component` elements in your input?

Comment: I want to add attribute in the component for which corresponding child (File elemeny) satisfy the condition that **source="SourceDir\Debug\settings.xml"**

Comment: @ michael.hor257k ... Thankx this is doing it right but the problem is , it is reoving file element too which is undesired. I need the file element as it is.